# Multilanguage UTF-8 website with Arabic

Tags: css, utf-8, arabic

I will be coding a website that will have **Arabic as a supported language**. With UTF8 unicode I believe I can cover Arabic alphabet. I've also read that it reads right to left so I guess I should align right when displaying on Arabic.

I'm asking the community for **experience and possible pitfalls**.

- utf-8 unicode
- css selector to swith text alignment

Thank you in advance for your input.

Comment: Take a look at http://balatarin.com

Comment: 'Align right' is only half of it.

Comment: @Itay Moav, nice looking site. I may have omitted but I can read Arabic.

Comment: @pavium, very true! Align right is only half of it. But the other will be auto-taken care of by the person writing the text, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/bidi-xhtml/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization could be useful.

Some things I can think of:

- your choice of colors and images could prove offensive or bad taste in some countries
- every image with text should be translated (image and alt); every image with directionality should be reversed (ex: an arrow)
- try to avoid class naming like `class="left"` if you don't want future headaches. Top, bottom, before or after are OK I think but not left/right.
- you'll have to check each CSS instructions about text-align, background-position, float, clear and obviously left and right with position: absolute/relative;
- different fonts need different font sizes (though this problem concerns asiatic fonts mainly)
- as for any other supported language, many bits of text in templates should be translated.

By "css selector to swith text alignment", do you mean `dir="rtl"` ? This is an HTML attribute. But you'll still need a class ('ll be fine on the body element) to act like a giant switch for your design needs. Like

```
.en .yourclass { background: url(images/en/bg.jpg) } 
.ar .yourclass { background: url(images/ar/bg.jpg) }
```

edit: an attribute selector would do the same but then there are those bad ol' IE ...

```
:lang(ar) .yourclass { background: url(images/ar/bg.jpg) }
or
[lang|="ar"] .yourclass { background: url(images/ar/bg.jpg) }
```

Comment: **:lang(ar) .yourclass** for work this, we need to set html attribute `lang="en"` or `lang="ar"`.

Answer (score 3):

> I've also read that it reads right to left so I guess I should align right when displaying on Arabic.

That's not enough, the direction must also be set as `rtl` (right-to-left). What you need is:

```
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.w3.org/TR/i18n-html-tech-lang/) is a good resource for declaring language in HTML.