# Changing text-alignment when keyboard is switched to a right-to-left language?

Tags: ios, safari, accessibility

As per an user-request I'm trying to make my (PhoneGap) webapp work better with RTL languages, such as Hebrew. I want to make my inputs and textareas work better with these languages. When the user switches their keyboard to such a language, the input direction automatically switches to right-to-left, as intended. However, the text-alignment stays on the left side, which is unfortunate. I realize I can switch the text-alignment using the *dir* attribute like so:

```
<input dir="rtl" />
```

My plan is to use JavaScript to somehow detect an RTL input language and add this attribute to all inputs and textareas. However, this seems like a bit of a hassle. Is there an easier way I'm overlooking? I don't like the idea of adding more JavaScript for this simple task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the whole page is written in hebrew or arabic, you should add the `dir` attribute on the `html` element, along with a `lang="he"` / `lang="ar"` attribute (the latter is for VoiceOver not reading hebrew/arabic believing it's english. The alphabet and pronunciation are quite different :) ).

If only parts of the page are written in hebrew, then each element containing hebrew text  should've these attributes (or its parent) and the other parts in english should've `dir="ltr" lang="en"` attributes so that no text is left without the appropriate `lang` and `dir` attributes. It's faster to add them on a single parent than on each individual HTML elements and if a parent has 5 nodes in english and 1 in hebrew, it only needs 2 attributes: 1 on parent for `lang="en" dir="ltr"`, the other on the child element containing hebrew.

For styling problems caused by rtl writing, you can use one of these attributes as a giant switch for each CSS property like `float` that uses `left` or `right` values (and properties like `right`, `border-right`, `margin-right`, `margin: t r b l;`; please see the second part of one of my first answers here on [UTF-8 and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780656/multilanguage-utf-8-website-with-arabic/1781056#1781056). Note: iOS has no problem with *advanced* CSS selectors that were only dreams when we had to support IE6 ;) )

Comment: Thanks for the informative write-up. However, it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I am wondering about how I can automatically make my text align to the right when an RTL language is chosen (iOS user switches keyboard). Currently, MobileSafari keeps the text aligned to the left, adding new characters at the "first" position (from an LTR viewpoint), which is kind of ugly in my opinion.